# match a file name pattern

Tags: linux, shell-script

So I have a pattern like `somepattern-abc-1.2.3-aji3mk3-11.tar`. I need to add a condition where

```
if [ $input matches somepattern[].tar ] 
then 
    do something
fi
```

here the `somepattern` will be a constant one, rest all till ".tar" will vary and can have a hyphen or a letter or a number. What can I replace my [] with so that it will be satisfied?

Comment: Can you please try to reword the following sentence, I am unable to make any sense of it: `rest all till ".tar" will vary and can have a hyphen or a letter or a number.`

Comment: Actually I think I may understand it but you will need to tell us exactly what `somepattern` is.

Comment: somepattern is something like "operator"

Comment: so in between operator and .tar we can have any pattern and this pattern will contain alphabet or number or  -

Comment: And also a dot `.`?

Comment: Also this is almost certainly an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You have a list of files that you are trying to filter certain files out of?  You should perform that filter when the list is initially generated.

Comment: As of your example `somepattern[-\.a-z0-9]*` could be a possibility.

Answer (score 3):

You can test with this:

```
input="somepattern-abc-1.2.3-aji3mk3-11.tar"

[[ "$input" =~ ^somepattern[-.a-z0-9]*\.tar$ ]] && echo "match" # here your command
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can write the pattern as a regexp then you have the `bash` operator `=~` that will compare the first argument with the regular expression on the other side.

You can test it with something like:

```
read a;[[ "$a" =~ "x" ]] && echo $a
```

where "x" is your pattern.

Comment: Note that if you quote the right hand side of `=~`, it becomes literal. `".*"`, for example, would match a dot followed by an asterisk.